# Infinite nulls received from readLine() method

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, client-server

I made an app which sends the accelerometer coordinates to my pc.The code for android side client is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
private SensorManager senSensorManager;
private Sensor senAccelerometer;
private long lastUpdate = 0;
float x ;
float y ;
float z;
TextView xt,yt,zt;
String st="left";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this,senAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    xt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xc);
    yt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yc);
    zt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zc);
    new SendMsg().execute();
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
      x = sensorEvent.values[0];
      y = sensorEvent.values[1];
      z = sensorEvent.values[2];
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
            long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = curTime;
            xt.setText(String.valueOf(x));
            yt.setText(String.valueOf(y));
            zt.setText(String.valueOf(z));

         }
    }
}


public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    senSensorManager.unregisterListener( this);
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    senSensorManager.registerListener( this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

private class SendMsg extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Socket s= null;
    OutputStream os;
    PrintWriter pw;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            s = new Socket("192.168.0.102",2345);
            os=s.getOutputStream();
            pw=new PrintWriter(os);
            while(true){
                pw.println(x+" "+y+" "+z);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "executed";
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
}
```

and the pc side server code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2345);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    System.out.println("message received from server is :");
    for (;;) {
        String ms = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("" + ms);

    }

}
```

Instead of sending the accelerometer coordinates it seems that the app is sending **NULL** and the same is being printed at the server side.

Despite trying hard i was not able to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried to put a 'log.d' statement to see what your are getting? Put in the next to the pw.println statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaken. TCP cannot 'send null'. The `readline()` method is *returning* null, * instead of you *receiving* data.

The reason is simpy that `readLine()` returns null at end of stream, and you aren't checking for it. This is clearly stated in the Javadoc. When it returns null, the peer has closed the connection, so you must stop reading and typically close the socket. The usual way to write this is:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What?  Surely, you are not expecting posters to Google system calls or read the man pages?